# Why I can't pass data as function in jQuery ajax dict but same data in variables working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm just starting with javascript and jquery. I'm using jquery ajax and i'm curious why one method of passing data in dict works but another none. What is wrong with second example?

Working example, I can get post data from dict

```
$('a.pop').click(function() {
      var multi = parseInt($('#multiplier').val());
      var prod = parseInt($('#producer').val());
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/myurl/post/",
          data: {multiplier: multi, producer: prod},
          success: function(data) {
            bootbox.alert("operacja wykonana poprawnie");
          },
          beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
          }
      });
});
```

In this one request post in /myurl/post/ is empty:

```
  $('a.pop').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/myurl/post/",
            data: {multiplier: parseInt($('#multiplier').val()), producer: parseInt($('#producer').val()), },
            success: function(data) {
              bootbox.alert($('#multiplier').val());
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: That works just fine. You'll have to update your question to include a [mcve]. There's no significant difference between putting the values in variables and then doing `data: {multiplier: multi, producer: prod}` and doing `data: {multiplier: parseInt($('#multiplier').val()), producer: parseInt($('#producer').val()), }` except that on some browsers the trailing `,` on the end of that will cause a syntax error and the ajax call won't be made at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('a.pop').click(function() {
      var multi = parseInt($('#multiplier').val());
      var prod = parseInt($('#producer').val());
      var obj = {
       multiplier:multi ,
       producer:prod
      }
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/myurl/post/",
          data: JSON.stringify(obj ,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(data) {
            bootbox.alert("operacja wykonana poprawnie");
          },
          beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
          }
      });
});
```

Comment: 1. Code dumps are not useful answers. Say *what* you changed, and *why*. 2. The OP's code is fine. 3. The code above, on the other hand, not only has a syntax error, but changes what the code is sending the server from something the server is expecting (standard form data) to something it clearly *isn't* expecting (JSON).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your code inside the document.ready because in 2 scenario it doesn't getting the value of Id

```
// A $( document ).ready() Once the page loaded then your script will run 
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    ...
    ...
 });
```